# Can argument to Rail's before_filter be a method in another class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

For example in

```
class C
  before_filter X
  ...
end
```

Can X can somehow be specified to be a method in another (non-super) class?

I'm wondering if this is possible by just changing the argument to before_filter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to call a class itself in a before filter, instead you could do this

```
class C
  before_filter :load_other_class_method
  ...

  load_other_class_method
    X.new_your_method #or loading your class
  end   


end
```